# how to slow down the picture when it springs back

Tags: java, android

I have written an app that can drag an image and then spring back the image. But the speed of spring back is too fast. I have tried but can't find a way to slow down it.

How can I control the speed of this?

```
public class CustomViewActivity extends Activity {

    float mx,my;
    ImageView switcherView;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_view);

        switcherView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img);  
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kh06);
        switcherView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        switcherView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {   
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {  
                float curX, curY;  
              //System.out.println(switcherView.getScrollX()+"--------view axis-----");
                switch (event.getAction()) {        
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  
                        mx = event.getX();  
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:  
                        curX = event.getX();    
                        switcherView.scrollBy((int) (mx - curX), 0);  
                        mx = curX;  
                        break;  
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                                                
                        switcherView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                        break;  
                }  
                return true;  
            }  
        });
    }
  }
```

scaleType of image is the center,the image hasn't been zoomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some code here

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                                                
    switcherView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    break;
```

Instead of directly moving back to 0,0 put a for loop and go to 0,0 from current position in many iteration. some thing like this.

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                                                
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                                myImage.scrollTo((int) mx, 0);
                                myImage.invalidate();

                            }
                        });

                        if (mx > 0) {
                            mx -= 1;
                        } else {
                            cancel();
                        }



                    }
                }, 100,10);
```

**Update**
This is code is working if you drag from right to left but when drag from left to right not working properly so correct it your self.

Answer (score 0):

The call `switcherView.scrollTo(0, 0)` in the case `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` tells Android to move the image to a specified location.

If you want to slow down this movement then you need to specify an animation in the `ImageView switcherView`

See [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) class. I suspect you just needed to be pointed in the right direction, Googling this provides many references.

Comment: thanks for your direction too,i have checked that  ,i want to upvote you but I have no permission ,so thank you